# MKLocalSearch produces SearchAttribution Error and Error Domain=GEOErrorDomain Code=-8

Tags: swift, mapkit, mklocalsearch, attribution

**I search places** with the MKLocalSearchCompleter and **refine the results** when the tableView cell is selected. When a MKLocalSearchCompletion is selected and MKLocalSearch.Request() is started, I get these Errors (example selects Los Angeles):
*According to my research this is a very rare problem?!*

- [SearchAttribution] No matching attribution source found for
  org.volunteermatch
  ... (+4 other domains)
- Error loading attribution info for identifier org.volunteermatch from
  geod: Error Domain=GEOErrorDomain Code=-8 "No matching    attribution
  source found for org.volunteermatch" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No matching attribution source found for
  org.volunteermatch}
  ... (+4 other domains)

These are the instance variables in a TableViewController:

```
var searchCompleter = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
var searchResults = [MKLocalSearchCompletion]()
```

This code is running everytime the search term is changed:

```
searchCompleter.queryFragment = text
searchCompleter.resultTypes = .address
searchCompleter.region = region
```

In tableView … didSelectRowAt… this code is executed:

```
let selectedItem = searchResults[indexPath.row]
        
let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request()
searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = selectedItem.title
searchRequest.resultTypes = .address
        
let search = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
search.start { (response, error) in
            
      guard let coordinate = response?.mapItems[0].placemark.coordinate else {
          return
      }
      // send to mainVC
     self.delegate?.userSelectedPlace(coordinate: coordinate)
}
```

**Xcode 12.4, iOS 14.4 Simulator**

Comment: Did you ever find a solution (or reason) for this?

Comment: Nope. Still getting these errors with Xcode 12.5.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar error when I tried to load search results into table view. Then I found that my table view's datasource and delegate is missing. So make sure your tableview's delegate and datasource outlets point to the right file owner.

[image]